Question on Poisson Process
I am trying to solve the following problem:
Jhon is a newspaper vendor. His customers arrive according to a Poisson process with a rate of one per minute. At any given moment, what is the probability that at least five minutes have passed since his last customer arrived? Suppose now that Jhon talks to every third customer. What is the probability that more than three minutes pass between one conversation and another? (Hint: consider that this is the probability that, in the three minutes following the first conversation, no more than two customers arrive.)
For the first question i guess that
$$
P(t \geq 5) = e^{-5}
$$
because the inter-arrival $t \sim Exp(1)$. For the other question I can not think of anything. I am thankful for any kind of help. Greetings.
Note: the question is from an old exam, and I think the questions are a bit ambiguous.

Your answer to the first part is correct.  The time that has elapsed since the most recent customer arrival is exponentially distributed, because interarrival times in a homogeneous Poisson process are exponentially distributed.
For the second part, how would you use the hint?  It is asking you to compute the probability that the number of arrivals in the next three minutes is less than or equal to $2$; i.e., if $N(t) \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ is the random number of arrivals in the interval $t \in [0, t)$, then what is $\Pr[N(3) \le 2]$?
Then ask yourself, why does the hint answer this part of the question?  Unfortunately, we must make some simplifying assumptions that are not explicitly stated in the question:  first, when the question talks about the time between one conversation and the next, no information is provided about the duration of the conversation.  So we can only assume that the time between conversations should be measured from the initiation of one conversation to the initiation of the next, rather than the time between the end of one conversation to the beginning of the next.  We must also assume that conversations are started immediately upon the arrival of a customer.
